# How to constrain the polar heatmap chart along the axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, polar-coordinates

I use a polar heatmap in matplotlib as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from energetics import compute_snr, DURATION_0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, ylim=np.pi/3)


rad = np.linspace(50, 1500, 100)
azm = np.linspace(-np.pi/3, np.pi/3, 100)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, azm)
z = compute_snr(distance=r,
                azimuth=th, angles='radians')
plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z, shading='nearest', cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I can constrain the data for the chart, but not the chart area:

[image]

There are no current methods for the Axes3D object:

```
ax.set_thetamin(45)
ax.set_thetamax(135)
```

These methods do not work:

```
ax.set_xlim([-np.pi/3, np.pi/3])
ax.set_ylim([-np.pi/3, np.pi/3])
```

How to constrain the plot along the axes? I want to get something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Why is `Axes3D` used while the plot seems to be 2D?

Comment: wow, thanks for bringing this up.
These are all copy pastes from examples.